# "space as AND" text search with couchbase

Tags: couchbase

With couchbase, I would like to retreive documents by finding words into their title.
The user will enter a string, the spaces will be seen as logical ANDs :

Let's say I have these documents :

```
{title : "My blue car is worderful", ...}
{title : "the sky is blue", ... }
{title : "mais ou est donc or ni car", ...}
{title : "president's car is blue", ...}
```

If the user enter "car blue" in the web interface, I would like to find :

```
{title : "My blue car is worderful", ...}
{title : "president's car is blue", ...}
```

How can I do that with couchbase ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Couchbase is not suited at all for free text search, luckily for you it does have a native plugin for integration with ElasticSearch which is great for free text search.  The Couchbase transport plugin replicates all data from your cluster to an ElasticSearch cluster in near real time, you could then use ES's abilities for free text search to provide this sort of functionality.

To get started with the Couchbase transport plugin go here:

http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-server/connectors/elasticsearch

More in depth article on setting up replication and configuration:

http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-elastic-search/#indexing-and-querying-data

Here is the link to ES documentation on text querying:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-text-query.html